# Javascript pull data from website (member site)

Tags: javascript, .aspxauth, data-scrubbing

I haven't written any code for this yet as I am trying to figure out how to do it first. I have a site at work that I have to log into with a password. Its a site that we use to manage our lanes (I work in transportation currently) the information is displayed as a popup across several taps.

What I need to be able to do is pull the data off of a field on the last tab (its the field that shows total amount for our loads) the page is a .aspx page so is it possible to scrub this? Is there another method without getting the service involved? I am trying to do my own analysis program but really confused on where to start with retrieving the data.

any helpful hints or links are appreciated.

Comment: You might want to look into http://phantomjs.org/

Comment: I will check that out, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Jquery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function that target and loads the returned HTML into your nominated result field. You also can target that specific field that you want.

$( "#result" ).load( "targetDomain/targetPage.html #targetField" );

Comment: That sounds like a great place to start. I was trying to stay away from Jquery because I prefer to stay vanilla while learning. If that works though it would be awesome. Thank you.